# UIImageView inside tableview changing frame position while scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm doing a instagram like have a table view whose cells contains an UIImageView. When it appears the first time the image views are positioned correctly, but after scrolling to next cells the image view's frame Y origin is moved from 0 to 15 pixels. I already tried to force the frame to the  correct position without success. here's my cellForRowAtIndexPath: code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    MITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kMITableViewCellID];
    MIPhoto *photo = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!photo.imageData) {
        if (self.tableView.dragging == NO && self.tableView.decelerating == NO) {
            [self startDownloadImage:photo forIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageViewBackGround.png"];
    } else {

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:photo.imageData];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

And here are the screeshots with correct and incorrect cell layouts

Correct layout screen:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t3r7w2wp6k8kot4/Photo%2008-12-13%2022%2046%2055.png

wrong layout screen:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/na7cb4a8shwc6mf/Photo%2008-12-13%2022%2047%2008.png

Comment: How do you add the imageview to the cell's contentView? Show some code may help

Comment: @KudoCC I did that using interface builder prototype cells.

Comment: What value did you set to imageView's frame and imageView's UIViewAutoresizing property?

Comment: The frame value is X = 0, Y = 0, width = 320.0, height = 320.0. I didn't set the autoresizing mask property, but the value that's being used is `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`

Comment: Try to use UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight instead.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but I solved the issue set the contentView's frame programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue setting the cell's contentView frame programmatically to desired values.

EDIT: I tried to figure out why the cell's content view was having it's frame changed, and I found what appears to be a bug at `layoutSubViews` method because the bug happens when this method is called by my custom `UITableViewCell` subclass.